# Wipe KDE5 Widgets via Command Line/Freezing issue

Tags: linux, arch-linux, kde, widgets, kde-plasma-5

I recently installed kde-plasma on an arch installation. Everything was working fine... until I added widgets. I wanted to try them out with a theme and decided that I wanted to remove them. However, when I right click to remove widget, the plasmashell desktop crashes (precisely it removes that one I deleted then the rest of the desktop freezes), leaving me unable to remove them. I can add more, the widgets are stable and usable, but they cannot be removed.

I have tried: deleting everything in ~/.kde4 (fresh install so not much to lose).

Along with: removing the app, killing the plasma shell and using kstart plasmashell to bring it back (the widget that got removed and caused the crash reappears).

Note: this happens for all widgets as far as I can tell (can confirm for Analog clock, launcher, calender, digital clock, sticky notes, cpu monitor, memory monitor...).

If all else fails I guess I can make a new user... but that does not fix the underlying issue. I can provide more info if necessary...

Answer (score 1):

Answer:

Changing the theme and removing the widgets after resolved the issue. I can only imagine that it's due to some unstable properties of the theme I selected (Sky Blue).